# Spring-boot banner.txt variables not processed

Tags: spring-boot

I don't seem to be able to get the banner.txt `${application.version}` or `${application.formatted-version}` variable processed and shown at runtime anymore.

Banner.txt is taken into account as it displays static text I added in.

I start the app packaged as a WAR file and it contains the `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` which in turn contains the expected `Implementation-Version`

I'm using Spring-boot v1.3.1.RELEASE, with Tomcat 8.0.30.

What could go wrong?

Comment: Are you deploying to a separate Tomcat instance rather than using an embedded container? There was a problem with earlier versions of Tomcat 8 (see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/3406) for details. Are you sure you are using 8.0.30? Perhaps there's been a regression. You could try another container (Jetty, for example) and see if it works there.

Comment: I'm using embedded Tomcat, and 8.0.30 is the version included, and I start it ```java -jar app.war``` to make sure the MANIFEST.MD is available.
I've been building the app and starting it with jetty, same problem (also with Undertow I believe but had an exception at startup, not really made to be started as prod server anyway)

Comment: It works for me with embedded Tomcat. Can you share an example project that reproduces the problem?

Comment: Please clone https://github.com/nodje/spring-boot-no-banner-variable. I have reduced the dependencies and the maven config to a minimum. If it works for you with a default project, I suppose it could come from a maven config conflict.

Comment: I am facing the same issue when we run java -jar instead of boot:run